# How can I see the call tree for SQL stored procedures offline (without actually creating them)

Tags: t-sql, tree, call

I have a huge SQL script which i need to analyse. It would be really helpful if i could find a way which can generate a call tree; ie, to see which all procedures are called from a particular procedure. a perl based example is here, http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2009/10/23/find-the-complete-call-tree-for-a-stored-procedure.aspx 
but i need a tool to analyse the text file (.sql file), not the procedure stored in the database. due to some reasons i will not be able to create the whole set of procedures in the database and use the above mentioned tool.

please respond if you have come across any ide/tool with this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not very helpful, as it violates your request for a "offline" sql file, text based parsing tool, but wanted to throw this redgate tool out there that I have used with great success in the past; [RedGate Sql Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-dependency-tracker/). It works very well and does a good job mapping out your objects and all their dependencies (definable as to what you want mapped). But it does require a database with all of the existing objects in place to work properly. :(

If you can't find one out there, I guess you could maybe do some script/macro text parsing if all the procedure calls are easily defined and predictable in the file. AutoHotKey is a great general purpose scripting tool/framework, and there are a few sql based scripts out there...just not one exactly like you are looking for that I have seen.

Comment: Thanks MikeCov. it appears to be no readymade solutions to do the processing in text files.  also to add to this, i figured out there is a dependency tree viewer in MS SQL Server management studio, you can right click any procedure from the object browser and select the corresponding option.

Comment: It didn't dawn on me until you just mentioned that, but management studio also has the 'Generate Scripts' task available from the database level that might be useful in that direction. In the object browser, on the database, right-click->Tasks->Generate Scripts...; there is an option in there to "Generate Script for Dependent Objects". Still not all the way there, but at least you could get all your dependencies in one file that way. I wonder if those third party tools use the same API/function calls to generate their dependency maps. :) Best of luck to you.